# Vlookup using formula for lookup_value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to use a `vlookup` formula where the lookup_value is a formula. If I use a value in that cell rather than a formula, the vlookup works just fine.

My Lookup-value is in cell D43 and the formula in there is `="B43/D41"`
My vlookup is `=VLOOKUP(D43,Sheet2!A1:B2992,1,FALSE).`

I get `#N/A` with this. When I change D43 to just a value (i.e. 1.21) it works.

Everything is formated as a number.

Help?

Comment: is the result of `=B43/D41` *exactly* `1.21`? Decimal precision would likely cause the NA result.

Comment: Otherwise try `=VLOOKUP(Round(D43,2),...)`

Comment: @pnuts, I did some tests. You are correct.

Comment: You also may change the last parameter in the VLOOKUP function from FALSE to TRUE (or omit it)  to get the closest match which is smaller than the search argument. This however requires that your lookup table  is sorted by the search argument (1st column) to avoid unwanted results.

Comment: @pnuts yes I suppose I do. I'll go ahead and add it...

Answer (score 1):

If the result of `=B43/D41` is not **exactly** 1.21, then an `#N/A` result will be expected, because the exact match (1.21) has not been found in the lookup array.

So the problem is the decimal precision in your lookup array is not the same as what's returned from your division.  Assuming your lookup array uses 2 decimals only then you could fix it like:

```
=VLOOKUP(Round(D43,2),...)
```